# C - How can we display "Hello World" without using semicolon

Tags: c

I want to display hello world message in c without using semicolon. how can I do that?
Is it possible?

Comment: Why? What is the problem you want to solve by doing that? Is it just curiosity? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I first thought of [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs) but unfortunately there is no semicolon :(

Comment: yeah, I am a beginner at c. just thought this question, that's y I asked.

Comment: I wonder why teachers give stupid assignments like this.

Comment: @michael walz it's not stupid. It gets the student to think of the material they have studied and putting them into use.

Comment: @machine_1 maybe, but there are certainly more productive assignments that teach the students how to do real stuff and not write artificial programs that nobody would ever write in real life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, It is possible.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   if(printf("hello world")){}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There you go!

## Solution 1

```
#include<stdio.h>
        int main(){
            if(printf("Hello world")){
            }
        }
```

## Solution 2

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    while(!printf("Hello world")){
    }
}
```

## Solution 3

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    switch(printf("Hello world")){
    }
}
```

## Solution 4

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define PRINT printf("Hello world")
int main()
{
    if(PRINT)
    {
    }
}
```